# Sanitize the different formats of CSV-formatted phone numbers

Tags: csv, awk, sed, ksh

Suppose there are several different kinds of CSV-formatted telephone numbers as follows:

Here is the first CSV file with lines as follows:

```
"Name","Address","FullPhone"
"Mike Wise","101 Abc Drive","4061234567" // Need to separate area code from the rest
```

Here is another CSV file with lines as follows:

```
"Name","Address","Areacode","Phone"
"Mike Wise","101 Abc Drive","406","123-4567" // Need to remove the dash in the seven-digit phone number
```

Is there some kind of sed one-liner to make it into the following universal format?

```
"Name","Address","NPA","TELNO"
"Mike Wise","101 Abc Drive","406","1234567"
```

I prefer sed one-liner, but if it has to be more than one line, so be it. Also, sed is not required. Just felt sed could be easier, though I didn't come up with a sed solution yet.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, they are in two different files, each of them has one format of the two. Thanks for reminding me of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\",\"" }
{
    if (NR==1) {
        $3 = "NPA"
        $4 = "TELNO\""
    }
    else {
        gsub(/-/,"",$NF)
        if (NF==3) {
            sub(/.{3}/,"&"OFS,$NF)
        }
    }
    print
}

$ cat file1
"Name","Address","FullPhone"
"Mike Wise","101 Abc Drive","4061234567"

$ awk -f tst.awk file1
"Name","Address","NPA","TELNO"
"Mike Wise","101 Abc Drive","406","1234567"

$ cat file2            
"Name","Address","Areacode","Phone"
"Mike Wise","101 Abc Drive","406","123-4567"

$ awk -f tst.awk file2
"Name","Address","NPA","TELNO"
"Mike Wise","101 Abc Drive","406","1234567"
```

and some specific input you didn't ask for but can probably occur and will be handled correctly anyway if it does:

```
$ cat file3
"Name","Address","FullPhone"
"Mike Wise","101 Abc Drive","406-1234-567"

$ awk -f tst.awk file3
"Name","Address","NPA","TELNO"
"Mike Wise","101 Abc Drive","406","1234567"
```

If you can have spaces you need to remove from the input phone number instead of just `-`s then just change `gsub(/-/,"",$NF)` to `gsub(/[-[:space:]]/,"",$NF)` or `gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$NF)` or similar.

Comment: Those listings are in two different CSV files. I also want to change the respective headers into the universal one with `"NPA"` and `"TELNO"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '1 c\
"Name","Address","Areacode","Phone"
     s/"\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\{7\}\)"[[:space:]]*$/"\1","\2"/
     s/-\([0-9]\{1,6\}\)"[[:space:]]*$/\1"/
     ' YourFile
```

will work on both your csv file format (also for header after the remark of @EdMorton)

- `1c \`: change the first line with the following line (force this one instead of original header)
- first s/// will change any line with ta trailing 3 digit followed by 7 digit (so 10 digit in 1 pack) surrounded by double quote with a 2 field value of 3 and 7 digit each using group feature of s///
- second s/// will change a trailing `-` followed by 1 to 6 digit and a double quote by the same without the `-` using group feature (ref by `\1`).

The first s/// will not take line of second sample (no pattern correspondance), the second will not take the line of first sample (same reason) and will alos not take line changed by first s/// (still same reason)
The second line

Comment: @EdMorton very good remark, I will change the code for that, sorry

Comment: right forget the digit catch on first substitution, correction done

Comment: Awesome, now it works perfectly. Could you elaborate a little bit on the second sed regex? Couldn't quite understand it yet. Thanks!